# react native phone verification issue

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-redux, reactive-programming

I was just working around with react native for implementing phone verification for android and ios version but when i tried the example version i couldn't get it working because it gives me a error: Oops! Network request failed.
I got no idea why is this so or have i missed any cruciel step and i couldn't possibly find any tutorial or enough support for that program anywhre so please tell me if iam missing anything.

Here is a screenshot of the error iam getting: https://preview.ibb.co/krbyFk/screenss_PM.png

This is the program i been trying to work around: https://github.com/joinspontaneous/react-native-phone-verification

## Edited, I see in the code that

```
const api = new Frisbee({
baseURI: 'http://localhost:3000',
headers: {
 'Accept': 'application/json',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }
});
```

Do i have to do something specifically about that?

Comment: Please add (if there is one) the stacktrace to your question.

Comment: @LunarWatcher Sorry mate none, well it would be much appreciated if you give a tutorial on how to setup the example repo with instruction other than written in the github page.

Please recheck my question.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting the same error because I was running this on emulator. when running on real device this error went . Also ensure that you have any dummy server running on the specified port.